# jQuery script only loads on frontpage

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm using the ScrollToFixed script for my navigation to create a floating sticky menu on scroll. However, it's only working on my front page, and not on any other pages. This is the code I have in my header, I know it's not good practice, but I could not get it to work when I tried to enqueue it.

```
<script type="text/javascript src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="wp-content/themes/neighborhood/js/jquery-scrolltofixed.js"></script>
</script>

<script>
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#main-nav').scrollToFixed();
});
    </script>
```

Comment: Could you provide a link or a fiddle?

Comment: It's because the path changes. Use an absolute path (`http://example.com/my-front-page-address/wp-content/themes/etc..`) instead of a relative path.

Comment: you forgot the closing " after type="text/javascriptX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

1. Put a slash in front of your jquery-scrolltofixed.js.  No starting slash makes it relative.
2. I really recommend getting your head around using WP's register/enqueue functions properly.  Check out http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-include-javascript-and-css-in-your-wordpress-themes-and-plugins--wp-24321

Trust me.  I did it your way for a while - it leads only to pain and damnation!

To explain your problem with the missing slash....  It's relative right...so, on the home page, it translates as:

```
mydomain.com/wp-content/themes/neighborhood/js/jquery-scrolltofixed.js
```

But on a category page for example mydomain.com/someCategory/my-awesome-post/, it will translate as:

```
mydomain.com/someCategory/wp-content/themes/neighborhood/js/jquery-scrolltofixed.js
```

because it's relative.  starting with / makes it absolute from your root domain.  This will fix your problem, but won't fix the greater problems you'll have without register & enqueue.

Comment: Thanks! Totaly missed the slash. Working now. And yes, I should and i will make it work the right way. Thanks for the link to the tutorial, will dive right in.